# What's the recommended way of loading data into Hive from compressed files?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I came across [this page on CompressedStorage](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CompressedStorage) in the documentation and it has me a bit confused.

According to the page, if my input files (on AWS s3) are compressed gzip files, I should first load the data with the option `STORED AS TextFile` and then create another table with the option `STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE` and insert the data into that. Is that really the recommended way?

Or can I just load the data straight into a table set with the option `STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE`?

If the former method is really the recommended way, is there any further explanation as to ***why*** it is?

Answer (score 0):

You must load your data in its format. It means, if your files are Text Files then you should load them as TextFile and if your files are Sequence Files then load them as SEQUENCEFILE.

For Hive the compression format doesn't matter because it will decompress them on fly using the extension of the file as reference (If the compression codec was configured properly in Hadoop).

The suggestion in the page that you are sharing is that it's better work with Sequence Files than Compressed Text Files. That is because a Gzip file is not splittable and if you have a very big Gzip file all the file have to be processed with only one Mapper not allowing work in parrallel distributing the effort among the cluster nodes.

Then the Hive's suggestion is convert Compressed Text Files into Sequence Files to avoid that limitation. It is only about performance.

If your files are small, then it doesn't matter (< 1 Hadoop block size - 128MB by default).

Comment: BTW, this apply for all frameworks working in hadoop, not only for HIVE.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In regards to your last statement `If your files are small, then it doesn't matter`, are you talking about files of any type? So if I have a `gzip` file of 100MB, it would not make any difference if I loaded it as a TextFile, right?

Comment: At least not a big difference. Text Files and Sequence Files have their own pros and cons. But even a GZip file is not splittable, you don't want to split a small file that imply to create more mappers. The "best" size for each block is defined in the default hadoop block size and it is 128 MB in the current version (unless you have a particular scenario). A good option could be merge all the files in a one big Sequence File compressed at RECORD LEVEL (not file leve as GZip).

Comment: In that case instead to have files with sizes: 100M, 28MB, 20MB . . . etc you will have a several GB's file but splittable in blocks of 128 MB. You need to decide if the effort and the pre-processing (create the big file) are justified in your case. And if you want to go deeper you should investigate about Columnar Formats like OCR or Parquet.